# compare 1 column in 2 files and print the different line

Tags: linux, diff, comm

I have file1 and file2.

file1:

```
a james
b mike
d john
```

file2:

```
a 10 20 30 40
b 11 12 13 14
c 20 30 40 50
d 10 20 30 50
```

I want the output file to only find the difference in column 1, and print that line for file2. In this case: C. so file3 look like:

```
c 20 30 40 50
```

I think the proper command is `comm`, but I don't think I'm using the right switches because every combination I can think of isn't giving me the right results.

Comment: So since you are mentioning `comm`, we can assume the first column is sorted? Great! As a first step: in a shell like `bash` that has process substitution we can do: `comm <(cut -d ' ' -f 1 file1 ) <(cut -d ' ' -f 1 file2)`

Comment: yep, the first column will always be sorted. I mentioned comm, but the list of commands that I can use are: comm, sdiff, diff, join, cmp. Using your command, that doesn't seem to print out cleanly. Instead it just has my file2 contents split up across the file

Comment: Huh? It should be a comparison of the first column, between `file1` and `file2`, you should see what is missing in `file2` on the left side, like I said, it would only be a first step. Oh and BTW, if you add `-13` to the `comm` call from me you will only see the differing entries in the first column, so you can then use this to select from `file2`: `grep "^$(comm -13 <(cut -d ' ' -f 1 file1 ) <(cut -d ' ' -f 1 file2))" file2`

Answer (score 2):

you can do this with awk

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1];next};!($1 in a)' file1 file2
```

Comment: I am really interested in how this works. I don't have much experience with multi-file `awk` and most tutorials aren't about it either.

Comment: awk seems to be the way to go here, but I have only been given comm, sdiff, diff, join, cmp as commands to use.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out!

```
join –v 1 file2 file1
```